# Linq To SQL select statement translates to Where 0 = 1

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq to SQL query.

```
var users = rdc.Users.Where(u => u.EmailAddress.Equals(emailaddress) && password.Equals(hash));
```

But it always translates to:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[Guid], [t0].[RoleId], [t0].[EmailAddress], [t0].[Password], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[Created], [t0].[Activated], [t0].[LastAction]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [t0]
WHERE 0 = 1
```

I just re-imported the tables into my DBML file to insure that the latest schema is reflected, but it still removes my clause and adds `WHERE 0 = 1`

I can use `ExecuteQuery<T>(string, params[])` but I want to find the root cause of this.

Comment: Please show the types of all relevant fields and variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are `hash` and `password` defined above this line? It looks like you might have forgetten to add the `u.` in your query. If `password` was already defined, then you wouldn't see an error, but it would never equal `hash`.

Did you mean to write:

```
var users = rdc.Users.Where(u => u.EmailAddress == emailaddress && u.Password == hash);
                                                                   ^^^
```

Also, @Mark pointed out that using the `==` operator will show errors that the `.Equals` operator might ignore.

Comment: +1 Good spot. Even if this doesn't fully solve the problem, the query should definitely be rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

For those, who also looking for solution, EF can set query filter on `WHERE 0 = 1` in case if your subquery always returns empty result. Maybe this is some kind of optimisation.
So, look closely on your subquery. Some expression there always turns it to empty result.

Example:

```cs
 return clientIds == null ? result : result.Where(r => ...);
```

Here, in subquery method return, if clientIds is `List<T>`, then expression will filter all results because list is always not null, even if it has no elements.
The correct way is like:

```cs
 return clientIds?.Count < 1 ? result : result.Where(r => ...);
```